# React JS - Avoid 'undefined' when rendering data via web API call in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Scenario:**
I am building React JS project where I have 3 components. Parent component, child Component and left-menu component. The left-menu component is part of child component. I am redirecting from parent component to child component using `<Link />` routing. The child component displays detail view based on the item clicked (`id`) in left-menu component. Very first time when redirection from Parent component to child component occurs, the `id` variable does not contain any value. Basically it throws null or undefined. (Although it is initialized with 0). This `id` is being passed as parameter in URL to make web API call which returns data to cater the detail view. This API call is executed using `useEffect` hook.

> Basically, the purpose is to handle the `id` variable in a way that when redirection occurs the page should not crash. Right now, it throws 400 - Bad request because the Web API call is seeing `undefined` as parameter.

**Code from Parent Component:**

```
<li key={index}>
    <Link key={index} to='/ChildComponent'>ABC Company</Link>
</li>
```

**Code from child Component:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const location = useLocation();
const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

let menuItemId = 0;
if (location.state !== null || location.state !== undefined) {
     menuItemId = location.state.menuItemId;
}

useEffect(() => {
const getUrl = window.location.origin + "/api/displayData/" + menuItemId;
const fetchData = async () => {
try {
   const response = await axios.get(getUrl);
   const data = await response.data;
   setDetails(data);
} catch (e) {
console.log('error', e);
}
};
fetchData();
}, [menuItemId])
```

So basically in above code when redirection occurs for the first time, the menuItemId is either 0 or undefined. How to recover this situation?

**Update: (Although I should have noticed this prior)**

I noticed that there is another component being referred inside child component and `prop` is being used to pass value of `menuItemId` to that another component. If I comment out that one, there is no more issue. I verified the `props` naming convention to ensure there is no mistake. Rendering inside child component is something like below.

```
return (
<>
<Row>
<Comments menuItemId={menuItemId} /> **(here it is throwing undefined)**
</Row>
</>
)

**code for comments component**
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const menuId = props.menuItemId;
```

Comment: I doubt that you are setting `location.state.menuItemId` instead of `location.state` to the `menuItemId` variable

Answer (score 0):

eitehr the if statement needs to be

```
if (location.state !== null && location.state !== undefined) {
```

or you can just use a fallback value when `location.state` is falsy with

```
// Replace the following
// if (location.state !== null || location.state !== undefined) {
//      menuItemId = location.state.menuItemId;
// }
//
// with

menuItemId = location.state?.menuItemId || 0
```

so when `location.state` is `null`, `undefined`, `false`, etc., the `menuItemId` will be assigned with a fallback value of `0` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your insight @Taiwei. Kindly find my update in my question. As I troubleshooted further and found the cause but still looking for resolution.